# Max app space (storage)

Tags: android

I've looked around and have noticed that the max size for an apk is 50MB, but I am curious as to how much application space an app can download.  Can one app take up all of the application storage or does it need to download additional content into the internal storage and/or sd card?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APK limit has been increased from 50MB to 4GB (see http://androidcommunity.com/android-market-upgrading-app-size-limit-to-4gb-20110511/ ), so one would presume that an app could store up to 4GB.

That said, you should be storing any large files on SD card (or similar) instead of taking up the app space (some phones this is shared space, such as the Galaxy Nexus.) Doing it that way won't have any limits except the space available on the SD card from my understanding.

Comment: The Market change that blog post refers to hasn't launched.  Android Market limit is still 50MB.

Comment: I thought it had been implemented already... well, at least it will be. I have also heard at a conference that Google are planning on allowing app's to store additional material in separate packages as well on the market (which will be useful for games,) though this hasn't been implemented either.